# new column with max difference in R

Tags: r, dataframe, difference, minmax

I have a dataframe like:

```
A   1 2 3 4
B   4 5 6 9
C   2 3 4 5
```

and I want to calculate the maximum difference for each row, and put it in new column:

```
A   1 2 3 4  3 (4-1)
B   4 5 6 9  3  (9-6)
C   1 3 4 5  4  (5-1)
```

Any ideas??

Thank you!!!

Comment: `apply(df1[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) max(x)-min(x))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There a multiple ways in which you can this. Two are mentioned in the comments. I like to use a combination of `range()` and `diff()`.

`range()` gives you the minimum and maximum value in a vector. `diff()` gives the difference between values in a vector. Applying `diff()` to the output of `range()` will therefore give you the maximum.

Using `apply()` with `axis=1`, does this rowwise for your data.frame:

```
df$X5 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) diff(range(x)))
df
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
A  1  2  3  4  3
B  4  5  6  9  5
C  2  3  4  5  3
```